# Keep functions to become methods on instantiation

Tags: python, class, methods

When a function is assigned to an attribute during class definition, this attribute stays an ordinary function with its original signature:

```
>>> def f(x):
    return x**2
>>> class A:
    ff = f
>>> A.ff
<function f at 0x037D6ED0>
```

When the class is instantiated, this attribute becomes a bound method and its signature changes:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.ff
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A object at 0x03A726B0>>
```

I need to define a class that I can later customize by changing some attributes **before** instantiating. One of these attributes is a function and I need it to keep it's signature.

Using `@staticmethod` is obviously not an option, since no function is defined on  class definition/customization, and decorations dont apply to attributes.

Is there any way to keep a function to be transformed into a bound method on instantiation?

Comment: *When a function is assigned to an attribute during class definition*. Note that using `def` inside a class definition is *also* assigning an attribute. That's because functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and only accessing the attribute on an instance does the binding action (producing a bound method).

Comment: This question has received 2 downvotes, with no explanation. I find this quite rude, and, frankly, not deserved. It would be apreciated if the downvoters could comment on their votes. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using @staticmethod is obviously not an option, since no function is defined on class definition/customization, and decorations dont apply to attributes.

No, `staticmethod` *is* the option, just call it directly to produce an instance:

```
class A:
    ff = staticmethod(f)
```

`@decorator` syntax is only syntactic sugar to produce the exact same assignment after a function object has been created.

This works fine:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x**2
...
>>> class A:
...     f_unchanged = f
...     f_static = staticmethod(f)
...
>>> A().f_unchanged
<bound method f of <__main__.A object at 0x10cf7b2e8>>
>>> A().f_static
<function f at 0x10cfb6510>
>>> A().f_static(4)
16
```

It doesn't matter where a function is defined, a `def` statement produces a function object *regardless where it is used*. `def name` is two things: creating the function object and an assignment of that function object no a name. Wether or not this takes place in a `class` statement or elsewhere *doesn't actually matter*.

What turns functions into bound methods is *accessing them on an instance*, as then the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) kicks in. For example,  accessing `A().ff` is turned into `A.__dict__['ff'].__get__(A())`, and it is the `__get__` method on a function that produces the bound method. The bound method is only a proxy for the actual function, passing in the instance as a first argument when called.

A `staticmethod` defines a different `__get__`, one that just returns the original function, unbound. You can play with those `__get__` methods directly:

```
>>> f.__get__(A())   # bind f to an instance
<bound method f of <__main__.A object at 0x10cf9f630>>
>>> A.__dict__['f_unchanged']  # bypass the protocol
<function f at 0x10cfb6510>
>>> A.__dict__['f_static']     # bypass the protocol
<staticmethod object at 0x10cf60f28>
>>> A.__dict__['f_static'].__get__(A())  # activate the protocol
<function f at 0x10cfb6510>
```

Comment: Well that's a big surprise. I guess I should have dug into the definition of the `@staticmethod` descriptor. Thx so much !